# NSdata to writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum bytes not exactly same?

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, nsdata

I am trying to save my **NSData** using **writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum**.

My **NSdata** size is '**49894**' and I saved it using **writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum**. if I read my saved image raw Data bytes using ALAssetsLibrary, I am getting my image size as '**52161**'.

I am expecting both as same. Can somebody guide me what is going wrong ?

Below link also not providing the proper solution.
[saving image using writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum modifies the actual image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623204/saving-image-using-writeimagedatatosavedphotosalbum-modifies-the-actual-image-da)

Answer (score 0):

You can not and should not rely on the size, firstly because you don't know what the private implementation does and secondly because the image data is supplied with metadata (and if you don't supply metadata then a number of default values will be applied).

You can check what the metadata contains for the resulting asset and see how it differs from the metadata you supplied.

---

If you need to save exactly the same bytes, and / or you aren't saving valid image files then you should not use the photo library. Instead you should save the data to disk in your app sandbox, either in the documents or library directory.

Comment: I need to save the exact bytes that is what my requirement. But the same scenario is working for some images. I didn't understand in what scenarios IOS will append additional bytes. That is the reason I posted this for help.

Comment: Why exact bytes? And why the library if you need exact bytes?

Comment: I have some encripted bytes in the last part of the image. So, I need to process my image as per the last part bytes. I am able to read and do the required actions and saving the image. While saving also i want to maintain the same number of bytes. But while saving some cases, automatically ios adding additional bytes. This is collapsing my algorithm.